# What type of encoding/compression is this? (web-app related)

Tags: security, encoding

I found this data in a response I received from my web server and I'm trying to understand it.

```
0000004d9GWDqAzpm/2u4Dzaqprpdcfzc+iZXVDL2IOYDzfqp3N5jvNDC4LABdpJ7dPEFs/pEIwHtpndY78pGtr90to3R/fU6leFc88U0z73A4yHFN0=
```

I know that that is base64 so I went ahead and decoded it to find the following string and I'm not sure what type of compression/encoding it's using.

```
ÓM4ÓNôe¨éý®à<ÚªéuÇósè]PËØ7ê§syóCÀÚIíÓÄÏé¶Ýc¿)ÚýÒÚ7G÷ÔêWsÏÓ>÷Ý
```

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: Do you have more data to go on than this? Do you have the whole log entry or email?, Where did it come from, what made this entry etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is unanswerable without access to the code which generated it (which the OP seems to have)

Comment: I'm doubtful the first 8 characters are really base-64 encoded. It's too surprising that they would just *happen* to encode to 6 zeros and then two hex digits. I suspect the first 8 bytes are the length of the message (0x4d=77). That leaves two bytes at then end (14dd) which could be padding or a checksum. But all of this is pretty useless guesswork. Reverse engineering a protocol almost always requires a lot more than one short message. Since you said it's your web server, I'd go investigate the code that's sending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Base64 decodes to data, not printable characters.

It does look like Base64 due to the character set used, the trailing "=" and the length being a multiple of 4 bytes. It also might not be Base64 encoded, see Rob's comment. It might be a combination with non-Base64 leading characters and the rest Base64.

In hex: `D34D34D34E1DF46583A80CE99BFDAEE03CDAAA9AE975C7F373E8995D50CB‌​D883980F37EAA773798E‌​F3430B82C005DA49EDD3‌​C416CFE9108C07B699DD‌​63BF291ADAFDD2DA3747‌​F7D4EA578573CF14D33E‌​F7038C8714DD`

But what this is is a mystery.

Note: Not all byte values are printable characters and most not ASCII or UTF-8 which explains the strange output you got.

Answer (score 0):

(this should be a comment, but its a bit long)

The short answer is no.

It might be encrypted, it might be compressed. The former usually (but not always) uses fixed size blocks - so the length of the byte stream may give an indication if this is the case. Given that there are 6 repetitions of a single character it is *unlikely* to be compressed. It might be a bitmap. Or a some bars from a midi file. Or....just about anything.

> in a response I received from my web server

Then you have far, far more access to determine what code emitted this (and therefore what it contains) than we do, however that you presented the output as a character stream suggests you have a very long journey ahead of you.